# Flutter for linux build fail

Tags: linux, flutter, gcc, flutter-linux

A linux build of any flutter application with linux enabled, results in the following error:

```
flutter run -d linux
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0008002
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010001
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010002
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../lib64/crti.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010002
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../lib64/crti.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010001
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/crtbegin.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010002
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/crtbegin.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010001
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../lib64/libgcc_s.so.1: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010001
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../lib64/libgcc_s.so.1: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010002
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../lib64/libgcc_s.so.1: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010001
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../lib64/libgcc_s.so.1: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010002
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/crtend.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010002
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/crtend.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010001
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../lib64/crtn.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010002
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../lib64/crtn.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010001
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: //usr/lib32/libdl.so.2: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0008002
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: //usr/lib32/libdl.so.2: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010001
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: //usr/lib32/libdl.so.2: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010002
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: //lib64/libdl.so.2: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0008002
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: //lib64/libdl.so.2: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010001
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: //lib64/libdl.so.2: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010002
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: //usr/lib32/libgcrypt.so.20: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010001
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: //usr/lib32/libgcrypt.so.20: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010002
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: //lib64/libgcrypt.so.20: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010001
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: warning: //lib64/libgcrypt.so.20: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0010002
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Building Linux application...
Exception: Build process failed
```

```
My flutter doctor:
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
• Flutter version 2.0.1 at /home/vtr/snap/flutter/common/flutter
• Framework revision c5a4b40 (9 days ago), 2021-03-04 09:47:48 -0800
• Engine revision 40441def69
• Dart version 2.12.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at /home/vtr/Android/Sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
• Java binary at: /snap/android-studio/current/android-studio/jre/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• CHROME_EXECUTABLE = /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
• clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
• cmake version 3.10.2
• ninja version 1.8.2
• pkg-config version 0.29.1

[✓] Android Studio
• Android Studio at /snap/android-studio/current/android-studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
hammer https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
hammer https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• android-studio-dir = /snap/android-studio/current/android-studio
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
• Note 7P (mobile) • • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)
• Linux (desktop) • linux • linux-x64 • Linux
• Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.72

• No issues found!
```

System info
System: Kernel: 5.9.16-1-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 10.2.1 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.21.2 Distro: Manjaro Linux

The error manifested upon upgrade of flutter to version 2.0.0
previous versions worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should update flutter (Channel stable) version to 2.0.3 . This version of flutter run don't have this issue.

### Updated answer

the universal solution for this problem is to uninstall flutter that you've installed  from `snap` and install it from `AUR`.

installing flutter from AUR-->`yay -S flutter`

you might encounter some permission problem. here's how to fix permission:

Create a new group `flutterusers`, add the default user to the group, then change permissions on the folder `/opt/flutter`.

```
sudo groupadd flutterusers
sudo gpasswd -a $USER flutterusers
sudo chown -R :flutterusers /opt/flutter
sudo chmod -R g+w /opt/flutter/
```

if you still got permission deny error,you can also change the permissions of the `/opt/flutter` folder to your `$USER`:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:flutterusers /opt/flutter
```

Comment: I'm usig Flutter 2.0.5 • channel stable • but I'm still getting this error.

Comment: i think you've installed "flutter" from "snap". Uninstall flutter from snap and installed it from yay (AUR).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using snap, a solution that worked for me is to install `clang` and the other build tools used by flutter, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69430293/8568263).