# Flutter Linux build error when executing flutter run -d linux

Tags: linux, flutter, cmake, build

Flutter doctor did not show any issues. What could be wrong?

executing: flutter run -d linux

Shows the following:

CMake Error at /snap/flutter/81/usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:45 (message):
The C++ compiler

```
"/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/clang++"
```

is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

```
Change Dir: /home/work/AndroidStudioProjects/myapp/build/linux/x64/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
                                                                    
Run Build Command:"/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ninja" "cmTC_0475b"
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_0475b.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
[2/2] Linking CXX executable cmTC_0475b                             
FAILED: cmTC_0475b       
 : && /snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/clang++    -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8 -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lblkid -lgcrypt -llzma -lpthread -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/ -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8 -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lblkid -lgcrypt -llzma -lpthread -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/ CMakeFiles/cmTC_0475b.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o  -o cmTC_0475b   && :
/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so: undefined reference to `gpgrt_get_syscall_clamp@GPG_ERROR_1.0'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.                                                                                                                                                                           CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project. Call Stack (most recent call first): CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)
```

Answer (score 5):

In `Linux Mint 20.2 Cinnamon` with `Flutter 2.5.2` and `snap 2.51.7`
I fixed by doing

```
sudo apt-get install clang cmake ninja-build pkg-config libgtk-3-dev
flutter clean
flutter run -d linux
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue with snap version of Flutter (https://snapcraft.io/flutter) April 15th 2021 release.

The solution is to do a manual install (https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#install-flutter-manually)

Comment: It's now Sep 2023 and I still have a similar issue which can be resolved by manually installing Flutter.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on ubuntu 22.04 use the flutter documentation for building and releasing linux app and install snapcraft here https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/linux

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31755691)

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled my mint and installed flutter manually and got the same issue

Comment: found solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72418645/flutter-error-cmake-error-debugging-new-project

Answer (score 0):

According to the link error log, the problem is a link to the libgcrypt cryptographic library, and the missing reference to the gpg-error library causes an undefined symbol error.

You can try the following ways to solve:

Make sure the gpg-error library is installed:

```
sudo apt install libgpg-error-dev
```

In the CMake compilation script, find the libgcrypt library reference and add the gpg-error library:

```
target_link_libraries(your_target libgcrypt libgpg-error)
```

If the flags are obtained through pgg-config, you can set them to:

```
pkg_check_modules(LIBGCRYPT libgcrypt libgpg-error)
```

After clearing CMake cache, the configuration is generated again and the reference sequence is correct.
If you are using the name version (libgcrypt.so.x) link, link to the libgcrypt.so library without the version instead.
Update the libgcrypt library to the latest version.
Essentially, you need to ensure that a reference to the gpg-error library is included when compiling and linking to resolve undefined symbol errors.