# Flutter Error: cmake error : debugging new project

Tags: flutter, dart, cmake, ninja, flutter-debug

I just start a new flutter project in vscode , when I want debugging the project , I got Error:

```
  Could not find compiler set in environment variable CXX:

  clang++.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
Exception: Unable to generate build files
```

I search on internet , and I found my "cmake" package , doesn't have g++.exe , so install it manually by following command line:

`sudo apt-get install g++`

but it doesn't work , how can I solve it?

Comment: Your `CXX` environment variable seems to be set to `clang++`, not `g++`. So either you need to install `clang++` or you need to configure your environment better.

Comment: I install clang using following command line: `sudo apt-get install clang` and i get a new error : `CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:463 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:643 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  flutter/CMakeLists.txt:25 (pkg_check_modules)
2

Exception: Unable to generate build files`

Comment: Post a new question with the _full_ output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution:

1- first run this command line :

```
sudo apt-get install clang cmake ninja-build pkg-config libgtk-3-dev
```

2- run `flutter clean` , but you must run it from your project root , done!

source : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67396100/flutter-linux-build-error-when-executing-flutter-run-d-linux/69430293#69430293)

Comment: also need : `sudo apt install libstdc++-12-dev`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the variables CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER, CMAKE_C_COMPILER in the linux/CMakeLists.txt before project() line

```
set ( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "pathto/g++" )
set ( CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/pathto/gcc" )
project(mytest)
```

source: [CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70524164/cmake-c-compiler-not-set-after-enablelanguage)