# Flutter A required package was not found flutter_secure_storage/linux/CMakeLists.txt:14

Tags: linux, flutter, cmake

A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/snap/flutter/101/usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:597 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/flutter_secure_storage/linux/CMakeLists.txt:14 (pkg_check_modules)

Comment: You probably need to add to the question post more information about what you are doing when you got given error.

Comment: on debug console shows only this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In [the doc of the package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) you can see it needs libsecret.

You just need to install the following packages:

```
sudo apt install libsecret-1-dev libsecret-tools libsecret-1-0
```

That worked for me :)

Comment: It didn't work for me. `libsecret-1-0 is already the newest version (0.20.4-0ubuntu1).`

Comment: Also `libjsoncpp1` is not needed since `hirsute (21.04)`, but `libjsoncpp-dev` is required.
Also my build failed with `unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0008002`. Needed to install flutter manually, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66614590/flutter-for-linux-build-fail) and [flutter doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux#install-flutter-manually)

Comment: work is this for ubuntu

Answer (score 10):

```
sudo apt-get install libsecret-1-dev libjsoncpp-dev libsecret-1-0
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 2):

If you, like me, already have libsecret-1-dev, libjsoncpp-dev and libsecret-1-0 installed, look in the message for the line of CMakeList.txt which error occurs:

> Call Stack (most recent call first): ...
> flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/flutter_secure_storage_linux/linux/CMakeLists.txt:14
> (pkg_check_modules)
>
> Line 14, in case: pkg_check_modules(JSONCPP REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET
> **jsoncpp**)

So, all you need is install the package missing. Im my case (Ubuntu 18.04) the package is libjsoncpp-dev:

```
$ sudo apt install libjsoncpp-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

I encounter the same issue on Fedora.

The solution for me was to run this command: "`sudo dnf install libsecret-devel jsoncpp-devel`".

Answer (score 0):

On my side, I removed the **firebase_ui_auth: ^1.1.6**  package from my project and it was able to run. I think there might be a bug in the package.
Run:

```
$ flutter pub remove firebase_ui_auth
```