# How to update chowned flutter on linux installed in /opt/ with yay from aur?

Tags: linux, installation, file-ownership

I installed flutter on linux into /opt/ folder from aur by yay. I found that I should change ownership from root to another user. Found some steps which suggested changing to exclusive flutter group so I chowned it and forgot about that. Maybe it was this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66614590/flutter-for-linux-build-fail).
And now I cannot update flutter installed because of the ownership rights.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution is to fix it [like this](https://github.com/mizzunet/Flutter-and-SDK-on-Arch-Linux#fix-permissions)

```bash
sudo groupadd flutterusers
sudo gpasswd -a $USER flutterusers
sudo chown -R :flutterusers /opt/flutter
sudo chmod -R g+w /opt/flutter/
```

And mentions:

> If you still get permission denied errors, you can also change the permissions of the /opt/flutter folder to your $USER:

```bash
sudo chown -R $USER:flutterusers /opt/flutter
```